# Searching in a large file on a mobile website

Tags: jquery, mobile

For a mobile website I'm loading a 8mb dictionary. The website uses jQuery Mobile so I'm using jQuery to load the file and store its data in a variable. When the user selects a word, jQuery reads the variable line by line until it finds a match. The performance on desktop is ok, but it's slow on mobile devices. Is this the best way to look up a word in a file? Should it be faster using a database? Any best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider placing all your data in a proper database and then perform a true query on this database. Scanning a 8 MB file every single time is an awful approach to your problem. Set up a database, put your data in a simple key/value table and then use for example PHP to execute queries on the database.

You should also consider what that means to mobile users: Every time they open your page, 8 MB of data is downloaded to the mobile device only to look up one word. Bad idea.